# Interested in learning struts 1.x

Tags: struts

I am working on a struts project which I am new to. I have the background in jsp, servlets and understanding of j2ee.

Is there any good sample struts sample project I can download and learn?

Comment: Why do you want to learn a completely out-of-date version? Why not the latest version?

Comment: my current project is using struts. Tonnes of spaghetti code is written in the project. Therefore, I want to find good struts sample project to learn from

Comment: How about the samples that come with Struts? There are tens of thousands of Struts 1 sample apps, blog postings, and even a few downloadable books available on the web.

Comment: I found [tutorial](http://www.vaannila.com/struts/struts-tutorial/struts-tutorial.html) for Struts Framework. You can easily understad about struts framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget learning from samples. I've seen Struts samples ranging from incomplete to complete, from very bad to very good. If you are new to Struts, chances are you will end up learning lots of bad practices that you will introduce in the project later to see that you did it wrong.

My suggestion would be to learn from a book. One that I personally liked was **Jakarta-Struts Live**:

[image: Jakarta-Struts Live]

It's relatively small (~270 pages, as opposed to your average IT book at ~700) and introduces you to most of the components you will use in day to day. Explanations are good and to the point.

Check it out if you can. If I'm not mistaken, it's freely available online.